# HQL Join in Grails

Tags: grails, hql

I am trying to execute a query to gather specific data but encountering problems in the query on the `on` portion of the query. To start off this is my class:

```
    class TimeSlot {

    String timeslot_id
    String time_chunk_id
    String uid
    String exam_id
    String start_time
    String is_special_arrangement

    static mapping = {
        table 'timeslot'
        id name: "timeslot_id", column: "timeslot_id"
        version false
        }
    }
```

This is the query I'm trying to get working:

```
TimeSlot.executeQuery("Select t.time_chunk_id, t.uid, t.start_time, t.timeslot_id, t.is_special_arrangement, e.length from TimeSlot t inner join Exams e on t.exam_id = e.exam_id where t.exam_id = ? and t.time_chunk_id = ?", [testArray[i], timeChunkArray[x]])
```

It's throwing an error on the `on` portion because it's expecting a clause, but I need the data to specifically pertain to the `exam.id` comparison of both tables. Is there another way around this or a different way to set up the query so it will work like it does in any SQL editor?

Comment: Use `with` instead of `on` in the query. HQL does not support `on` keyword. Its equivalent is `with`.

Comment: That took away the error but now it's saying in can't resolve the symbol `t` at `t.exam_id = e.exam_id`. Any Suggestions to why that's happening?

Comment: Use `from TimeSlot as T, Exams as e where t.exam_id = e.exam_id`.

Comment: I'm trying not split this into two different queries as it would not yield the same results pertaining to that specific query I'm currently trying to use.

Comment: If you do not know it already, you can map the domain object against the `exam_id` column. Like `exams column: exam_id` inside `TimeSlot` where exams is `Exams`

Comment: Query should look like this Purchase.executeQuery(
    "select p.customer from Purchase p join p.items i where i.product = 'Pencil' "), I wrote a tutorial here http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-hql-queries

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you alter the domain class and add one to many relationship

```
class TimeSlot {
    static hasMany = [examinations:Exams]
```

Then HQL can be

```
select ... from TimeSlot t join t.examinations e
```